# Meteorite trouble with exec-sync

Tags: meteor, npm

I've installed Meteor, Meteorite with `npm`.

```
sudo npm install -g meteor
sudo npm install -g meteorite
sudo npm install -g exec-sync
mrt create myapp
mrt add router
mrt add typescript
```

When I try to add a simple smart package like `typescript` I run into trouble. Meteorite seems download the smart package, and reports `Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!`. But this follows:

```
/home/fushunpoon/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/405cd9e86c6336bd9aaa7a8f240bb9815dceed2d/app/meteor/meteor.js:669
}).run();
   ^
Error: Cannot find module 'exec-sync'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
...
```

(the stack trace continues).

I saw the advice on the `meteor-typescript` `README` that advises people do

`sudo npm link exec-sync`

but this doesn't fix the problem. Any ideas what's wrong?

EDIT: version information:

```
$ meteor --version
Meteor version 0.5.6 (aaa86c3e2d)

$ mrt --version
Meteorite version 0.4.7
Meteor version 0.5.6 (git checkout)

$ npm --version
1.1.62
```

Running on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: try npm cache clean and then try again

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply but no luck, same problem.

Comment: Any difference if you install Meteor from docs.meteor.com with curl rather than using npm?

Comment: Did you run `npm install -g exec-sync`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'll update the question..

Comment: Could you check `npm list -g` and `sudo npm list -g` and see if `exec-sync` is there?

Comment: `exec-sync` can be found in both lists!